# Find file on SFTP server that contains string content in Python

Tags: python, optimization, sftp, pysftp

### Problem

In Python, my task is to find a file `(XML)` on an external `SFTP` server that contains

```
<myTag>BLA</myTag>
```

The problem is there could be more than 5000 files on the server.

Is there a way to do it efficiently?

### Right now I am:

- using `pysftp` to connect to `SFTP` server
- gather all filenames from there and filter them to include only .xml
- go over files with `conn.getfo(file_name, file)` to get the file and search for content.

### Pseudo code

```
import pysftp
cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
cnopts.hostkeys = None

conn = pysftp.Connection('...', username='...', password='..', port=22, cnopts=cnopts)

all_file_names = []
    for file_attr in conn.listdir_attr(root):
        filepath = f'{root}/{file_attr.filename}'.replace('//', '/')
        if stat.S_ISREG(file_attr.st_mode):
            all_file_names.append(filepath)
        elif stat.S_ISDIR(file_attr.st_mode):
            if skip_path is None or skip_path != filepath:
                all_file_names = all_file_names + get_all_filenames(filepath)

for file_name in [f_name for f_name in all_file_names if f_name.endswith(tuple(['.xml']))]:
    with tempfile.TemporaryFile(mode='wb+') as file:
        try:
            conn.getfo(file_name, file)
            file.seek(0)
            file.read()
            # find right tag...
```

This code takes around 0.15s per file to open it. Because I have 5000 files this is 12,5min to go over all of them.

### Question

How to optimize this?

### Prerequisits

- The SFTP is outside of my domain
- I do not have SSH permissions
- There is not a viable solution to download and store all files on my server (file sync)

Comment: If you have write permission and just want to read you shouldn't open the files with `'wb+'` just in case you mess up something.

Comment: If you only have an SFTP access, then what you have done is the best you can get. + *"There is not a viable solution to download all files on my server"* – But that's exactly what your code is doing.

Comment: No, I just store it in a memory for parsing and then forget about it. :D

Comment: Nevertheless, you are downloading all the files, just not storing them - which is probably less than optimal, as you have to download them all again next time you have the same problem; if you store them locally, you only need to examine the ones which are new or changed.

Comment: *"Store it in a memory"* is imo *download*. It is not relevant that you do not store the contents to a physical local file.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl - agree. What I meant was to sync files with my local storage and then do some other "magic" :D Is there any implementation detail that I need to be aware of? - like using stat.S_ISREG instead of conn.isfile speed up tremendously....

Comment: Well, once you have a file list, you could open parallel connections to the server to speed things up (e.g. `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor`...).

Comment: sftp is a (deliberately) thin protocol -- it doesn't let you do anything actually efficient (running a search remotely, where the data is). If given this challenge, I would start by talking to the folks who run the server and trying to figure out if there's a way to get the content into an indexed database -- if you could run XQuery operations against it this would all be trivial, because otherwise, as others have said, you're transferring all the data you need to search -- whether you store it or not.

Comment: Mind, you can certainly run more threads, over more connections, to try to saturate the network and I/O bandwidth -- the gains are limited, but if you're doing everything in serial there _are_ gains to be had.

Comment: ...but really, I'd go with a frame challenge for whatever organizational limits are putting the data outside the space you can index and query it. If it's worth assigning a developer for multiple days to find a way to do this efficiently, it's (hopefully, if your organization values their dev-hours) worth spending the infrastructure costs to have something that's _actually_ efficient (think "completing arbitrarily-complex searches in seconds" if done right), vs tinkering around the edges.